# Fetching JSON with TRON

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I would like to fetch a JSON file which is located: http://online.basket.ee/s2/list/2017-03-01/data.json

It does not look like a RESTful API so I am bit confused.

```
let tron = TRON(baseURL: "http://online.basket.ee")

    class JSONError: JSONDecodable {
        required init(json: JSON) throws {
            print("JSON ERROR")
        }
    }

    fileprivate func fetchTodayFeed() {

        let request: APIRequest<TodayDS, JSONError> = tron.request("/s2/list/2017-03-01/data.json")

        request.perform(withSuccess: { (todayDatasource) in
            print("Succesfully fetched our JSON object")

            self.datasource = todayDatasource

        }) { (err) in
            print("Failed to fetch JSON", err)
        }

    }
```

I have fetched JSON the same way from my own RESTful API which I created using Node.js and Express.

So my question is it even possible to fetch that kind of JSON or what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

it worked for me. 
try

```
 let tron = TRON(baseURL: "http://online.basket.ee/s2/list/2017-03-01")
```

then

```
let request : APIRequest<Source,JSONError> = tron.request("data.json")
```

If you want to work with url like "https://example.com/blabla?id=test" you have to do something like this

```
let tron = TRON(baseURL: "https://example.com")

let apiRequest : APIRequest<SourceJSON,JSONError> = tron.request("blabla")

daysLeftRequest.method = .get
daysLeftRequest.parameters = ["id":"test"]
```

Comment: Still does not work. No errors but just blank page where my fetched data should appear.

Comment: I fixed this problem by accident. I changed Allow Arbitrary Loads to YES in info.plist